# SQLite join error?

Tags: sqlite, r

I am trying to join two tables in an SQLite database using RSQLite

When I use this statement,

```
SELECT table1.*, table2_1.values AS values_1 
FROM table1 JOIN table2_1 
ON table1.row_names=table2_1.row_names
```

I get this error:

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near "values": syntax error)
```

As far as I can tell, the SQL statement is valid for SQLite? I wonder if my error is obvious.

Comment: :) i get the same error when i try your code.. so there is something wrong there..

Comment: Thanks for confirming - I guess `VALUES` is an SQL keyword. ...but my tables already have fields named `values`...

Comment: ;-) yes thats right, you cannot use keywords for column and table names.. Sqlite is flexible, but not that flexible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and confirmed.. ;-) never use keywords as column names or table names, see:http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

```
select table1.*, table2.columnname AS values_1 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.examplename=table2.examplename;
```

Comment: The problem is that SQLite's `ALTER TABLE` also does not allow renaming of fields. BUT using `table2_1.'values' AS val_1` and "guarding" the `values` name with single quotes works.

Comment: :) that's an option to indeed. But when you keep using that name, you will get in the same error again and you will again look for the cause. But it is your choice, everybody is free to use their own column names..

Comment: I already have the table, and the table is large so recreating it will take another day. So that's pretty much my only option.

Comment: you can rename the column, if you like

Comment: example:
ALTER TABLE {tableName} RENAME TO TempOldTable;

CREATE TABLE {tableName} (name TEXT, COLNew {type} DEFAULT {defaultValue}, qty INTEGER, rate REAL);

INSERT INTO {tableName} (name, qty, rate) SELECT name, qty, rate FROM TempOldTable;

DROP TABLE TempOldTable;

Comment: Ha - not exactly renaming as much as creating a new table :) but thanks. ...but won't you also run into trouble since there is a column called `values` in `TempOldTable` so `SELECT` could only be used with `*`.

Comment: You are right it is creating a new table and no, when you use a columnname that only contains a keyword there is no problem. Else you wouldn't be able to use any words that contain "as". It just can't be an exact keyword.